# Binance.us order api throwing 'Not all sent parameters were read' error

Tags: http, binance, binance-api-client

I'm working with the binance.us API for a small app and am testing the order endpoint.

I have validated that the API key I am using is correct (receive 401s when it is not included or typed wrong) and that it has the permissions to make orders.

I'm attempting to make a LIMIT order via http POST to the endpoint at https://api.binance.us/api/v3/order as a test.

This is the order I'm trying to send over to complete the request. Don't mind the quantities I'm not expecting to get a bitcoin for a dollar here, I just want to validate that such an order can go through:

```
{
'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 
'side': 'BUY', 
'type': 'LIMIT', 
'newOrderRespType': 'FULL', 
'recvWindow': 10000, 
'timeInForce': 'IOC', 
'quantity': 1, 
'price': 1, 
'timestamp': 1624734129, 
'secret': '<my secret>'
}
```

And this is the returned response (with an HTTP 400 code)

```
{
'code': -1104, 
'msg': "Not all sent parameters were read; read '9' parameter(s) but was sent '10'."
}
```

Plugging in more optional fields yields the same 'read  but was sent ' message. What does this mean? How can I go about fixing this to properly submit an order?

Comment: Have you contacted their support?

Comment: I have not yet. I was hoping to get a quick answer on what that error code means so I can just make the necessary change before I submitted an official ticket.

Comment: Did you figure this out? This is where I am stuck at too.